# Prove a sequence of functions is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

- Context

I am reading the text book *Calculus With Applications, by Peter D. Lax* and have a problem in the section of 'Approximating $e^x$'.

The way to do this is to take the functions **$e_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$** and prove they converge uniformly to the function $e^x$.

The problem I confront is in the first step, which is **to prove the sequence $\{e_n(x)\}$ is bounded.**

- Complete problem description

Show that for each $x>0$, the sequence $\{e_n(x)\}$ is bounded. *Hint:* For $x<2$, $e_n(x)<(1+\frac{2}{n})^n$. Set $n=2m$ to conclude that $e_m(x)<e^2$.

- My progress

The confused part to me is the hint, and I wrote something like:

for $x<c$

$e_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n<(1+\frac{c}{n})^n$

let $n=cm$

$e_{cm}(x)=(1+\frac{x}{cm})^{cm}<(1+\frac{1}{m})^{m\cdot c}=e_m^c$

Now I'm stuck, especially don't know how to do with $e_{cm}(x)$

- Other thinking

Since the book does not clearly define the bound of a sequence of functions and how to find it. I want to make sure if it is the same as I thought: For a sequence of functions to be bounded, we need to prove that for every $x$ (in their common domain D), the **sequence of numbers** $\{f_n(x)\}$ is bounded.

Comment: For a sequence of functions to be bounded in this context, you need to prove that all the sequences $(f_n(x))_n$ are bounded by the *same* constant. Here you just wanted to have each of these sequences be bounded separately so it's fine, but you haven't shown that the sequence of functions is bounded, if that's what you actually wanted.

Comment: @BrunoB I think I get what you mean and it's the difference between uniform boundedness and pointwise boundedness, right? What we need is uniform boundedness, which is a stronger property.

Comment: Yes exactly. You won't have uniform boundedness of $(e_n)_n$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ here though, but with TheSilverDoe's answer you can have uniform boundedness on every $[0, c]$ for all $c > 0$ for example, just by saying that for $x \leq c$, $e^x \leq e^c$, and $e^c$ depends neither on $n$ nor $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ : there exists $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$, one has $\dfrac{x}{n} > -1$.

Then for $n \geq N$, you have
$$0 \leq e_n(x)= \left( 1 +\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n = \exp \left[ n \ln \left( 1 +\dfrac{x}{n} \right)\right] \leq \exp \left[ n  \times \dfrac{x}{n} \right] = e^x $$

where I used the inequality $\ln(1+u) \leq u$ for every $u>-1$.

So the sequence $(e_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is bounded.

Comment: I think your answer is really great and very helpful to me (despite that you didn't use the hint given in the book), thanks a lot.